# How to get the name of a coroutine in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I'm curious about the internal working of a coroutine when `suspended` on the main thread. The real question is how to log a `suspended` function which is a coroutine on the main thread. Where exactly the execution is taking place? Is it a virtual thread?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you are talking about logging the coroutine name:

You can achieve this by

1. Give name to coroutine(if you want custom name): `launch(CoroutineName("My-Coroutine"))`
2. Enable the logging in IntelliJ toolbar menu: Run -> Edit Configuration and add

`-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug` in VM options.

[image: VM Option in Edit Configuration]

Then you can see `@My-Coroutine` in logcat.

Try below code after Edit Configuration change:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
println("   'runBlocking': I'm working in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")

val job = launch(CoroutineName("my-custom-name")) {
    println("   'runBlocking': I'm working in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")

}

job.join()}
```

Result: 
[image: Result]

Comment: How to do the same for multiplatform and/or Native?

Comment: Where is Vm Options? I used Android Studio 4.1.1 and in Run/Edit configuration..only found VmOptions inTemplates/kotlin. Is that the same you mean?

Answer (score 11):

The other answers don't answer the question directly "*How to get the name of a coroutine in Kotlin?*"; instead, they suggest how to name a coroutine.

If inside a coroutine, the name can be retrieved using `currentCoroutineContext()[CoroutineName]`.

If outside a coroutine, there's no direct way to retrieve the name using a reference to a `Job` or `Deferred` (too bad). However, there's a reflection hack that can be used. Of course, the usual warnings come attached, which are, no type safety and hacking into internal APIs that may change anytime.

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
val nameString = AbstractCoroutine::class.memberFunctions
    .single { it.name == "nameString" } as Function1<AbstractCoroutine<*>, String>
val name = nameString(job as AbstractCoroutine<*>)
    .replace("\"", "")
    .takeWhile { it != '#' }
```

The method/function containing this code has to be marked with `@InternalCoroutinesApi`.

Answer (score 5):

You can give name to coroutine using `CoroutineName(name:String)` method at the time of creating coroutine:

```
repeat(5) {
            GlobalScope.launch(CoroutineName("$it")) {
                displayGreetingsFor(it)
            }
        }
```

To retrive the name given to coroutine use `coroutineContext[CoroutineName.Key]` as shown below:

```
private suspend fun displayGreetingsFor(i: Int) {
        delay(100)
        println(
            " ${coroutineContext[CoroutineName.Key]} is executing on thread : ${Thread.currentThread().name}"
        )
    }
```

This is will print following o/p on console:

```
CoroutineName(0) is executing on thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-3
CoroutineName(1) is executing on thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
CoroutineName(2) is executing on thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-8
CoroutineName(3) is executing on thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-6
CoroutineName(4) is executing on thread : DefaultDispatcher-worker-5
```

Comment: Don't encourage usage of `GlobalScope` by including that in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `CoroutineName("some name")` as others have mentioned

To print CoroutineName, there are 3 ways:

**Method A**

`System.setProperty("kotlinx.coroutines.debug", "on" )` will make Job.toString() include the name

e.g.

```
"my coroutine#4":StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@b735e2c
```

**Method B**

Inside each scope, printing the CoroutineContext.toString() will include the name

e.g.

```
CoroutineContext: [CoroutineName(my coroutine), StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@b735e2c, DefaultDispatcher]
```

**Method C**

Quite similar to method B, for Job objects, we can print `(Job as CoroutineScope).coroutineContext`.

Take note that (Job as CoroutineContext) does NOT work! (not sure why but `(Job as CoroutineContext).get[CoroutineName]` returns null)